# how to do a sum or ave in Web API 2 , OData v4 , EF6

Tags: entity-framework, asp.net-web-api2

i found a solution like this ~/Sales?$apply=aggregate(Amount with sum as Total)
but WebAPI look like no support it.
any replacement for it ?

Answer (score 0):

Using the LINQ extension `QueryByCube` ([www.adaptivelinq.com](http://www.adaptivelinq.com), you can expose an *auto-aggregate* view queryable by OData.
For example you can build a service queryable as follows :

```
~/SalesAutoAggregateView?$select=TotalAmount
```

Disclaimer: I'm the AdaptiveLINQ developer.